# Site Collection Doesn't Open with SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I created a new web application and a site collection. When I open the site collection on SharePoint Designer 2013, I clicked Open Site, but my site disappear under Microsoft SharePoint Designer Web Sites.

[image]

I checked Enable all options for SharePoint Designer Settings under Site Collection Administration. But I can't see my new site collection still, and I can't open the site with SP Designer. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Might be a silly question but the user account you are using in SP Designer has proper access to that site collection, right? Also can you test if you can open any other site collection through Designer?

Comment: And what happens if you enter your site URL in 'Site Name' textbox and then click open? I am not sure but I think you need to open your site at list once before your site will show in this list.

Comment: @Vedran I tried your advice but I got this error message 'Server Error: There is no web named "".' . I tried now and it opened. I guess, have to wait a while for be active.

Answer (score 1):

Check your account settings since you may have used your SPD elsewhere. SPD 2013 > Account > Switch Account.

It's a common problem since SharePoint Designer doesn't give the right error message!

Comment: it didn't need. I tried open site again, it opened. I guess, have to wait a whike for be active. Thanks for your answer.